# findstr in batch not giving expected result for strings having '!" in between text

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a batch file which is getting the last line from a file(.txt or .js).
But, if my end string(or line) is having any "!" mark, I am not getting the expected string(or line).

The batch file looks like:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('findstr /r /i /c:":" %1' ) do set LASTLINE=%%s
echo !LASTLINE!
```

So, for my input file, which is sample.txt:

```
BEGIN
Country : US
Country : UK
Text : Welcome! Pleasure to have you here.
END
```

I am getting:

> Text : Welcome Pleasure to have you here.

Expected:

> Text : Welcome! Pleasure to have you here.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

Move `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` below `for` loop, so it does not interfere with your content

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%s in ('findstr /r /i /c:":" %1' ) do set LASTLINE=%%s
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo !LASTLINE!
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked as expected. But can you please explain, why its not working with strings having specifically "!" mark?

Comment: see answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355733/batch-file-replace-exclamation-mark-with-escaped-exclamation-mark